# Как изменить цвет ячейки таблицы на срок 24 часа, в которую были внесены изменения

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, laravel

Есть таблица "Проекты". Каждый проект, соответственно, имеет свой id, по которому можно задать дополнительный класс каждой строке в таблице "Проекты".

Возникла необходимость добавить класс ячейке какого либо проекта в таблице html на определённое время. Но как это сделать не могу понять. Ведь id есть только у 
каждого экземпляра проекта, т.е. у целой строки в таблице. А у ячейки нет никакого идентификатора.

Данные извлекаются из базы данных MySql. Работаю с Laravel.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы изменять цвет ячейки таблицы на срок 24 часа, в которую были внесены изменения. Хотел реализовать с помощью добавления класса каждой ячейке со стороны сервера, т.к. таблицей пользуются несколько человек с разных рабочих мест. Если добавить класс ячейке с помощью JS то как его сохранить в бд, чтобы изменённая ячейка отображалась и на других рабочих местах?

Прошу направить на правильный путь, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: если на стороне сервера, можно добавить как вариант таблицу содержащую в себе id проекта, наименование столбца, время редактирования. и при обращении к таблице проектов сравнивать с этой таблицей на предмет изменений и добавлять нужный класс к ячейке в указанном столбце и с id проекта.

Comment: Принцип понятен. Но ни разу не реализовывал. Случайно нет похожих тем с решением или приблизительного кода для всего этого?

Comment: начните пробовать реализовать, и уже где будут проблемы задавайте вопросы.

Comment: В общем я совсем запутался.  Создать таблицу с колонками id проекта и название колонки. А как их сравнивать при обращении к проекту, если я использую laravel и eloquent orm для извлечения массива проектов из базы данных и потом в представлении использую цикл foreach для записи каждого проекта в строку таблицы представления.

Comment: Ну вы же как-то собирались подсвечивать строку по её идентификатору, но была проблема с ячейкой, так я вам посоветовал создать доп таблицу с ид проекта и столбцом, так свяжите эти таблицы и выводите пользователю, а дальше дело за обработкой информации и присваивания стиля. С laravel и eloquent orm  не работал, с ними не помогу. Выкладывайте код и указывайте проблему где и что не получается.